# t4 generate file with no DependentUpon attribute in csproj file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, t4

We are using t4 templates for managing configurations in our project. And web.config file is generated via web.tt file. After generation in csproj file I have following:

```
<Content Include="Web.config">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Web.tt</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

Is it possible to configure t4 template somehow to generate independent web.config file, not under web.tt?

[image: Web.config file depends upon web.tt]

Comment: Can I ask why this makes a difference?

Comment: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1210

Comment: Not very clean but you could remove web.tt from the project and create the web.config file using TextTransform.exe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx) as a pre or post build action? Ultimately this seems to be a problem of nuget but while you are waiting for the bugfix maybe this could mitigate your pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. First define a save routine in a T4 include file.

**SaveOutput.tt**:

```
<#@ template language=“C#” hostspecific=“true” #>
<#@ import namespace=“System.IO” #>
<#+
  void SaveOutput(string fileName)
  {
      string templateDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
      string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(templateDirectory, fileName);
      File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString()); 

      this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(0, this.GenerationEnvironment.Length);
  }
#>
```

Now every time you call SaveOutput with a file name it will write the current buffer to that external file. For example.

**Web.tt**:

```
<#@ include file=“SaveOutput.tt” #>
<#
    GenerateConfig();
    SaveOutput(”..\..\Web.Config”);  
#>
```

If you want to generate multiple files:

```
<#@ include file=“SaveOutput.tt” #>
<#
    GenerateFile1();
    SaveOutput(”..\..\File1.txt”);  

    GenerateFile2();
    SaveOutput(”..\..\File2.txt”); 
#>
```