# Generate .net projects through T4

Tags: c#, .net, t4

How can I generate .net projects through T4? I have a .edmx with my model and a T4 template. I need to generate different projects architect ($name_solution.models, $name_solution.data.EF, $name_solution.interface, etc.)

Comment: Usually you use a t4 templates to generate whatever output off some other source.  What is your source?  Project files are just xml so in general its possible to generate them.  If you don't have some specific source, then I'm wondering if possibly custom project templates would suite your needs better?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247120.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the SaveOutput implementation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980215/t4-generate-file-with-no-dependentupon-attribute-in-csproj-file/7218105#7218105). It shows how you can redirect output to multiple files using T4.

Using this it's possible to hand craft a project file and save it accordingly.

Comment: For multiple files I really like Damien Guard's Manager class. http://damieng.com/blog/2009/11/06/multiple-outputs-from-t4-made-easy-revisited